# How to check if one given time, i.e, Starttime is not greater than another given time, i,e, EndTime in ksh shell?

Tags: datetime, unix, ksh

I have two inputs, a `StartTime` and `EndTime`.I have to check if the `StartTime` entered is not greater than the `EndTime`. If so, it has to display an error.

My input format is

```
./filename Jan 10 16 20:00:00 Jun 12 16 00:00:00
```

I am using the logic as,

```
$Start=$(date --date="$1 $2 $4 $3" +%s)
$End=$(date --date="$5 $6 $8 $7" +%s)
if [[ " $Start" > "$End" ]]
then
{
    echo "Starttime cannot be greater than endtime"
    exit
} 
fi
```

This code works in bash shell, but shows an error for the `--date` function in ksh shell. Any idea how I can replace the function to work in ksh shell?

Comment: Which `ksh` version are you using? Works fine on Modern ksh93: `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` there are some issues in the variable assignments though. Remove the `$` sign before variables `Start` and `End` i.e. `Start=$(date --date="$1 $2 $4 $3" +%s)` and `End=$(date --date="$5 $6 $8 $7" +%s)`
`

Comment: Are you comparing bash and ksh on the *same machine*? If you're comparing bash on a Linux box with ksh on a traditional Unix box (AIX/HP-UX/etc.) it may actually be a difference in the available `date` command and whether or not it's the GNU version. Non-GNU versions don't accept the long argument format `--date`, but instead just want `-d`.

Comment: Can you replace the input format to `./filename 2016-01-10 20:00:00 2016-06-16 00:00:00` ? Than you can compare the strings `"$1 $2" > "$3 $4"`.